# What's the difference between the usage of different and other in these contexts?

Tags: difference, understanding

[Source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/other)

> The journey is called off, replanned for some other time.

Source:A School Prospectus

> The school has well equipped computer labs. The students use the facilities to develop software, which are not useful only to the school but also to other organisations.

In the second sentence, I believe comma is unnecessarily used.

What difference would it make if I replace **other** by **different** in these sentences. I believe **different** is a must for the second sentence in place of **other**
.

Answer (score 0):

Think of this

> Different [from] : refers to two things not being the same. *New York is different from Los Angeles [because it has Skyscrapers]*.

and

> Other [than]: refers to things that might be the same in terms, but are not the same. *Which cities exists, other than New York and Los Angeles?*.

The software can be used by other organisations *[other schools or other organisations].*

The software can be used by different organisations *[different organizations from schools, maybe municipalities, unions or some completely different organization]*

Answer (score 0):

You're mistaking "other" with "different"

The different is usually an other, but "other" does not mean "different"

"Other" just means "not this one", "different" means "not the same".

So "other organizations" doesn't mean "different organizations"

The usage of "other organizations" imply they have similar ways of doing things, and generally speaking similar goals

"Different organizations" means they're not similar, either in goal, way of doing things, etc. Such that you can theoretically group a bunch of "other" organizations together under a single banner to work towards a common goal, but you can't do that with "different" organizations